# In multi level Categories (Parent - child relationship) can one child had two or more parent?

Tags: php

**Single child related to multiple parent**

For example:

| Parent categories | Child categories |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 8 |

But in my case I want `child 7` to have *two (or more) different parents*,

| Parent categories | Child categories |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 7 |

Is this possible with a MySQL query or anything in PHP?
In the table we can only add one integer value in the column `parent`

Comment: One of the solutions : Just add another data column for linking with the 2nd parent.

Comment: but what if it has more then two or three parents

Comment: most simple solution is to use loop and make single query for each parent.

Comment: there is multiple questions & answers about it for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514834/mysql-php-creating-multiple-parent-child-relations

Comment: Pls use many-to-many relationship if more parents

Comment: matin hrabal i have try above code but not work for me and hello @KenLee please can explain little more how do i use many to many relationship in above example

Comment: There's no such thing as mysqli query. Mysqli is an extension used to send SQL queries to MySQL